# Heap corruption on free() after WM_DROPFILES

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have to malloc some memory to create a weird structure for the WPARAM on this message, but after calling PostMessage I can't free the memory without the program crashing saying there was heap corruption.

```
void DropFileMsg(HWND hWind,char* file_path)
{ 
    DROPFILES* drop_data = (DROPFILES*)malloc(2048);
    char* files = (char*)drop_data+sizeof(DROPFILES);
    ZeroMemory(drop_data,2048);

    drop_data->pFiles = sizeof(DROPFILES);
    drop_data->pt.x=0;
    drop_data->pt.y=0;
    drop_data->fNC=false;
    drop_data->fWide=false;

    strcpy(files,file_path);
    PostMessage(hWind, WM_DROPFILES, (WPARAM)drop_data, NULL);
    free(drop_data);
}
```

Heap corruption error: Invalid address specified to RtlGetUserInfoHeap( 002F0000, 00300018 )

This works totally fine without the `free`, and also without the `PostMessage` but not with both. Why is this?

**This has nothing to do with it being freed too early as suggested in the top answer, *stop upvoting it*.  If that were the case this question wouldn't be about heap corruption but rather would have caused an access violation.**

Comment: How do you declare `drop_data`? How do you allocate it? How do you use it? You don't write beyond the bounds of the allocated memory? And finally, have you tried running in a debugger to make sure it's actually in the `free` call that the crash happens?

Comment: What is the string length of `file_path`?

Comment: Um, the drop structure needs to be an `HDROP`, not a block of memory allocated by `malloc`. The drop recipient is going to call `DragFinish` on an invalid `HDROP` and chaos will ensue.

Comment: The `WM_DROPFILES` message is not application-generatable. It requires special handling (`HGLOBAL` marshaling) which is not available to applications. The operating system does wacky internal stuff, and if you try to post the message yourself, the wacky internal stuff will not work. (For example, it will call `GlobalSize` to get the size of the memory block, but since you didn't allocate the memory with `GlobalAlloc`, you get garbage.)

Comment: @RaymondChen So if I call GlobalAlloc with GHND will this fix the problem?

Comment: You might like to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RaymondChen "on an invalid HDROP" -- but it wasn't invalid, it was just allocated from the wrong pool. As the documentation says, "The HDROP variable is now a handle to a DROPFILES structure followed by a double null-terminated string containing the fully qualified file paths of the copied files" -- his code produced that. But the memory allocated with `malloc` was freed by `GlobalFree`, which corrupted the heap, which is why `free` crashed. And that's consistent with it "working" without `free` (but the memory was leaked) or without `PostMessage` (making the code a no-op).

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because the recipient of the `WM_DROPFILES` message uses the pointer, but you have already unallocated it so the pointer now points to unallocated memory and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of you freeing the memory, why not let the recipient free the memory when done?

Comment: @Nowayz Then you *still* have undefined behavior. A pointer in one process is not valid in any other process, each process has its own (virtual) memory map. You can use [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

Comment: @Nowayz The [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is *asynchronous*, it doesn't wait for the recipient to receive the message, which means you can free the memory before the recipient receives the message. And like I said, two processes can't use the same pointer, it will simply not work so you have a design problem there as well.

Comment: @Nowayz As for your crashing, if it crashes in the `free` function, then you do something you should not do. Have you debugged to know that it actually crashes in the `free` function? How is `drop_data` allocated?

Comment: It likely either crashes when the dangling memory (which is dangling because you just freed it) is accessed by the other guy processing the message (which the other guy does after free, because PostMessage returns immediately and doesn't wait for anything to handle the message it posts); or when you're freeing memory not actually available to your process (because you got it from another process, already freed it, or otherwise are freeing an invalid pointer).

Comment: @Nowayz EDIT YOUR QUESTION! Please update your questions with all these details then, because otherwise everyone would keep on guessing! SO is not a debugging service, and without enough details (like how you use the pointer, or how you allocate it) there's no way we can answer it.

Comment: @Nowayz AND heap corruption will most definitely happen if you write to unallocated memory (the data-race problem you really do have).

Comment: @Nowayz It doesn't matter, it's still a data race. `PostMessage` returns *immediately*, Windows may (or may not) continue to run your process, there is nothing to say that the recipient will handle the message (fully or partially or at all) before you free the memory. That is indeed a really big problem and which can indeed cause heap corruption.

Comment: Order of operations: (1) malloc.  (2) PostMessage.  (3) free.  (4) Other guy gets message.  (5) Other guy uses message.  (6) You come here, asking what's wrong.  (7) What's wrong is that 5 is after 3 because 2 is asynchronous, causing your failure.

Comment: If you can use SendMessage, that waits until the message is processed.  If not, the receiver should free the memory.  The goal is for memory not to be freed until the receiver finishes doing something with it; then to be freed.

Comment: @Nowayz The operative word here is "copied", it's the *pointer* that is copied in the message, and not what it points to. It's a so called *shallow* copy.

Comment: @Nowayz Then you are most likely writing beyond the bounds of the allocated memory, and I'm back to the questions I posted to your question (and here too): What are you doing with the memory? How do you use it? Also another one, *who* allocates the memory? And *where*? And don't answer here in comments, ***update your question!***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60057/discussion-on-answer-by-joachim-pileborg-crashing-on-free-after-postmessage).

Comment: This answer is completely wrong by the way, I have explained why the heap became corrupted in my answer.  It's because the memory is freed in this singular instance by the receiving context using GlobalFree

Comment: @Nowayz Did you forget what you wrote in the question? "This works totally fine without the free, and also without the PostMessage but not with both." -- without the `free`, `GlobalFree` scribbles on your heap memory, which is then leaked. Without the `PostMessage`, of course there's no problem -- you `malloc` some memory and then `free` it. But with both, `PostMessage` scribbles on your heap memory and then `free` barfs because the heap has been corrupted.

Comment: "It's probably because the recipient of the WM_DROPFILES message uses the pointer, but you have already unallocated it so the pointer now points to unallocated memory and you have undefined behavior." -- this isn't some abstract language definition for which behaviors are unknowable, it's concrete executing code. Freeing memory does not generally unmap the pages, so the memory being "unallocated" is irrelevant. Rather, the memory is freed by two different libraries--`GlobalFree` and then `free` -- we know the order because `free` crashes ... because `GlobalFree` corrupted its heap.

Comment: @HWalters We know that's incorrect because `free` crashed. What actually happens is the `PostMessage` copies the data and then calls `GlobalFree` on it -- which corrupted the heap because the memory came from `malloc` -- which caused `free` to crash.